# Joinable PriorityQueue in python's asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, queue, python-asyncio

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html), there are several implementations of Queues. The ones I'm interested in are the JoinableQueue and the PriorityQueue, as I'd like to have a joinable queue with priorities.

It appears that I can only get one of the functionalities in the lower versions. I.e. in 3.5 I can make the distinciton with Queue (which is joinable) and PriorityQueue, but in python below 3.5 there is JoinableQueue and PriorityQueue (see example below).

Is it possible to combine them to get a general way to get a joinable PriorityQueue in 3.4?

```
try:
    # Python 3.4.
    from asyncio import JoinableQueue as Queue # joinable
    from asyncio import PriorityQueue          # I assume this one is not joinable
except ImportError:
    # Python 3.5.
    from asyncio import Queue                  # standard joinable
    from asyncio import PriorityQueue          # I assume this is the one I want
```

Another approach would be to somehow perhaps influence Queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the way `JoinableQueue` and `PriorityQueue` are implemented, you can get a `JoinablePriorityQueue` by subclassing both via multiple inheritance, as long as you list `JoinableQueue` first.

The reason this works is that `PriorityQueue` is very simply implemented:

```
class PriorityQueue(Queue):
    """A subclass of Queue; retrieves entries in priority order (lowest first).

    Entries are typically tuples of the form: (priority number, data).
    """

    def _init(self, maxsize):
        self._queue = []

    def _put(self, item, heappush=heapq.heappush):
        heappush(self._queue, item)

    def _get(self, heappop=heapq.heappop):
        return heappop(self._queue)
```

While `JoinableQueue` is more complicated, the only method both it and `PriorityQueue` implement is `_put`, and crucially, `JoinableQUeue` calls `super()._put(..)` in its own `put` implementation, which means it will cooperate with `PriorityQueue` properly.

Here's an example demonstrating that it works:

```
from asyncio import PriorityQueue, JoinableQueue
import asyncio
import random

class JoinablePriorityQueue(JoinableQueue, PriorityQueue):
    pass


@asyncio.coroutine
def consume(q):
    while True:
        a = yield from q.get()
        print("got a {}".format(a))
        if a[1] is None:
            q.task_done()
            return
        asyncio.sleep(1)
        q.task_done()

@asyncio.coroutine
def produce(q):
    for i in range(10):
        yield from q.put((random.randint(0,10), i))
    yield from q.put((100, None)) # Will be last
    asyncio.async(consume(q))
    print("waiting...")
    yield from q.join()
    print("waited")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
q = JoinablePriorityQueue()
loop.run_until_complete(produce(q))
```

Output:

```
waiting...
got a (1, 2)
got a (2, 1)
got a (4, 4)
got a (5, 0)
got a (6, 8)
got a (6, 9)
got a (8, 3)
got a (9, 5)
got a (9, 7)
got a (10, 6)
got a (100, None)
waited
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way to get your attention, knowing you were involved with aio :)

Comment: @PascalvKooten I didn't develop any of the core `asyncio` code, just a third-party module (`aioprocessing`) that's built on top it. That and I've answered lots of questions about it here on SO. [Andrew Svetlov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3454879/andrew-svetlov), who also answers lots of questions on asyncio here, did develop some of the core code, I believe.